# How to cite an online article with hyperlink to its online source in bibliography section

Tags: hyperref, natbib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get DOI links in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography)
>   [biblatex: Make title hyperlink to doi url (if available)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available)

I use TeXShop, BibDesk and NatBib, and am a beginner with BibDesk and the whole bibliography job. I am trying to cite articles with `hyperref` (that I already know how) but want to have hyperlinks in the bibliography section to online articles.  How can I hyperlink so that only the title but not the web address shows up?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you posted one or two bib entries, as BibTeX processes them differently depending on their type (article, book, techreport, misc, ...).

Comment: Do you mean you want to do something like `title = {\href{http://www.somewebaddress.com}{This is the title of the article which will be a clickable link}},` in each entry of your `.bib` file?  (Of course, this kind of solution requires you use the `hyperref` package.)

Comment: What do want to clickable? The title? Then the above solution is what you need. If you mean you're trying to cite to some url, I'd suggest creating a `@misc` entry, with a `note` that includes the url, using the `hyperref` package. We could provide some more detailed info if you provide some more detailed info about what you're trying to achieve precisely

Comment: From what I understand, I have had the same question some time ago, and I have reported the solution I found in this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography/64695#64695. There are probably other related posts here that can help you get on tracks, depending on what you want.

Comment: I think you can use my question of yesterday http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70514/adjusting-a-constant-in-a-bst-file-plainurl-bst with the excellent answer from @egreg. Very quick and efficient.

Comment: the faq (which no-one bothers to read) has http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=citeURL