# adjusting a constant in a *.bst file (plainurl.bst)

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, links

I am using `plainurl.bst` style, Miktex 2.8, `pdflatex` to generate a `pdf` file. It gives explicitly the URL of my `bib` file. I would like to get this link attached to the title  (i.e. embedded below the title) instead. Essentially the explicit url is most often too long and generate a bad box and if the URL changes the printed  and `pdf` version does not change.

Opening `plainurl.bst` I find

```
% The following constants may be adjusted by hand, if desired

% The first set allow you to enable or disable certain functionality.
#1 'addeprints :=         % 0=no eprints; 1=include eprints
#1 'adddoiresolver :=     % 0=no DOI resolver; 1=include it
#1 'addpubmedresolver :=     % 0=no PUBMED resolver; 1=include it
#2 'hrefform :=           % 0=no crossrefs; 1=hypertex xrefs; 2=hyperref refs
#0 'inlinelinks :=       % 0=URLs explicit; 1=URLs attached to titles
```

I just don't know how to adjust by hand `inlinelinks := 1`.
If I write 1 in the code above I get the message

```
:= 1 is an unknown function---line 72 of file plainurl.bst
```

I also tried in the tex file to write 
`\bibliographystyle{plainurl}[inlinelinks :=1]` 
not better.

So it is just a question of how and where I can adjust, I guess it was obvious for the code writer, but I did not find a documentation for it.

Comment: You should copy `plainurl.bst` under another name, say `myplainurl.bst` and change `#0 'inlinelinks :=` into `#1 'inlinelinks :=`. Then call `\bibliographystyle{myplainurl}`; save the modified file in the same directory as your document.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks a lot @egreg. The question can be closed, ... I don't know how!

Answer (score 7):

You should copy `plainurl.bst` under another name, say `myplainurl.bst`.

Change the line

```
#0 'inlinelinks :=
```

into

```
#1 'inlinelinks :=
```

Then call `\bibliographystyle{myplainurl}`; save the modified file in the same directory as your document.

The `#` tells that the following token is to be interpreted as an integer. More important is that the language used in `.bst` files is in reverse Polish notation, so

```
#0 'inlinelinks :=
```

means "set the variable `inlinelinks` to the integer value 0".

More information on the language is in ["Tame the BeaST"](http://texdoc.org/pkg/tamethebeast), available on TeX Live distribution by `texdoc tamethebeast` (the file is called `ttb_en.bst`).