# Is it possible to make a reference clickable without showing its DOI or URL field?

Tags: biblatex, urls, doi

I'm using `biblatex` with the following options

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,%
    isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
```

Thus, my bibliography contains neither `url` nor `doi` fields, making it nice and short. However, this comes with the disadvantage that references no longer contain clickable links leading to the download location of that particular source.

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Have you considered the possibilities offered by `eprint` and `eprinttype`?

Comment: you can edit the format of `url` and `doi` and only print the words `url` or `doi` with the hyperlink to the download location (And using `doi=true` and `url=true`, of course).

Comment: Where's a person supposed to click on if the doi and url fields aren't shown?

Comment: Preferably on the publication title but the author name or the whole reference would work just fine as well.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**: Added Title clickable (1. just the title cickable and 2. the whole reference clickable)

## 1. Just the Title reference clickable

You can redefine the `title` macro and add the `\href` to the `title` using the `DeclareFieldFormat`. I edited the default definitions in the `biblatex.def` file.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\myhref{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\myhref{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}}
```

And the macros are:

```
\newcommand{\doiorurl}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
       {}
       {\strfield{url}}}
    {http://dx.doi.org/\strfield{doi}}%
}

\newcommand{\myhref}[1]{%
 \ifboolexpr{%
   test {\ifhyperref}
   and
   not test {\iftoggle{bbx:url}}
   and
   not test {\iftoggle{bbx:doi}}
  }
  {\href{\doiorurl}{#1}}
  {#1}%
}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,%
    isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{usingdoi,
  author={The First Author},
  title={Using DOI},
  year={2014},
  journal={J. Med. Sc.},
  publisher={Springer},
  doi={10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.3865},
  pages={1-2},
}

@Article{usingurl,
  author={The Other Authors},
  title={Using URL},
  number={2},
  year={1998},
  month={4},
  journal={ACM Trans. Inf. Sys.},
  publisher={Springer},
  volume={16},
  pages={127-160},
  url={https://www.google.com}
}


@Article{nodoiurl,
  author={The Author},
  title={Neither doi or url},
  number={2},
  year={1998},
  month={4},
  journal={ACM Trans. Inf. Sys.},
  publisher={Springer},
  volume={16},
  pages={127-160},
}

\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\doiorurl}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
       {}
       {\strfield{url}}}
    {http://dx.doi.org/\strfield{doi}}%
}

\newcommand{\myhref}[1]{%
 \ifboolexpr{%
   test {\ifhyperref}
   and
   not test {\iftoggle{bbx:url}}
   and
   not test {\iftoggle{bbx:doi}}
  }
  {\href{\doiorurl}{#1}}
  {#1}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\myhref{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\myhref{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}}



\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}%XXIII
```

[image]

## 2. The whole reference clickable

I found a way that allow to make a reference clickable (The whole text of the reference is clickable)

For this I Modified the definition of `DeclareBibliographyDriver` to add a `\href` to the full reference.

This is necessary before  `biblatex` load the *bibliography style*.

By default, before load the style files, `biblatex` try load the file `biblatex-dm.cfg` (*biblatex custom data model*), then it is possible modify the `DeclareBibliographyDriver` using this file.

I created  the file (`biblatex-dm.cfg`) in the work directory with the content:

```
\newcommand{\doiorurl}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
       {}
       {\strfield{url}}}
    {http://dx.doi.org/\strfield{doi}}%
}

\newcommand{\bibdrivercontent}[1]{%
 \ifboolexpr{%
   test {\ifhyperref}
   and
   not test {\iftoggle{bbx:url}}
   and
   not test {\iftoggle{bbx:doi}}
  }
  {\href{\doiorurl}{#1}}
  {#1}%
}

\let\OldDeclareBibliographyDriver\DeclareBibliographyDriver
\renewcommand{\DeclareBibliographyDriver}[2]{\OldDeclareBibliographyDriver{#1}{\bibdrivercontent{#2}}}
```

This code use `\href` only if `hyperref` is loaded and `doi` and `url` options are `false`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,%
    isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{usingdoi,
  author={The First Author},
  title={Using DOI},
  year={2014},
  journal={J. Med. Sc.},
  publisher={Springer},
  doi={10.1007/0000-0xz},
  pages={1-2},
}

@Article{usingurl,
  author={The Other Authors},
  title={Using URL},
  number={2},
  year={1998},
  month={4},
  journal={ACM Trans. Inf. Sys.},
  publisher={Springer},
  volume={16},
  pages={127-160},
  url={https://www.google.com}
}


@Article{nodoiurl,
  author={The Author},
  title={Neither doi or url},
  number={2},
  year={1998},
  month={4},
  journal={ACM Trans. Inf. Sys.},
  publisher={Springer},
  volume={16},
  pages={127-160},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the `biblatex-dm.cfg` file to my working directory and it indeed made all those references clickable that contain `url` or `doi` fields. However, if I click on one, [doi.org](http://www.doi.org) says page not found, as in this [case](http://www.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.3865). I'm not very familiar with this stuff. Do you know what could be causing the problem?

Comment: It is my mistake. In the `doiorurl` _macro_ change the `www` by `dx`. It means: the line  `{http://www.doi.org/\strfield{doi}}` is replaced by  `{http://dx.doi.org/\strfield{doi}}`. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: @PacificOrion You're welcome. I edited my answer and I added how to make only the title clickable.

Comment: That's even better. Tested it and works as well. Perhaps you edit your answer so that instructions on on how to add the link to just the reference title come first, as it is simpler and probably what most others would be looking for.

Comment: A similar approach without the need for another document is posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464290/215950). Thanks for your solution anyhow, made me find this one.