# biblatex: Hyperlink entire bib entry to DOI, URL or ISBN if available

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, urls, doi

This is kind of a combination of two questions and then I have a bibliography style problem on top of that.

I would like to make each bib entry into a hyperlink with the priority: 1. DOI, 2. URL, 3. ISBN/ISNN. It has earlier been shown how this is done for the title of the entries in [biblatex: make title hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn). However, I am using a bibliography style which does not show titles (chem-angew). I would like the entire entry to become a hyperlink. This has been done only with DOI in [Hyperlink each bib entry to its DOI page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84133/hyperlink-each-bib-entry-to-its-doi-page).

My first problem is, when I use the chem-angew style and I include an entry with a DOI, the DOI shows, even though I include DOI=false in the usepackage (and the DOI is not supposed to show up in the chem-angew style):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha},
doi = {doi},
url = {url},
issn = {isbn-issn},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

My second problem is, when I add:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldundef{url}
    {}
    {\href{\thefield{url}}{\usedriver{\thefield{article}}}
    \csdef{blx@bbx@\thefield{entrytype}}{}}%
}
```

to my local biblatex.cfg file, the bib entry will have the biblatex style and not the chem-angew style as asked for in the same way as my earlier MWE.

[image]

The final problem is the priority of the hyperlink which I would like to add to the entries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one solution that tries to link the entire entry (minus the label). `string+doiurl` is a simplified version of [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)'s `string+doiurlisbn` from [biblatex: make title hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newbibmacro{string+doiurl}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
       {#1}
       {\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
    {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@driver#1{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@#1}
    {\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@#1}}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@bbx@*}
       {\blx@warning{%
          No driver for entry type '#1'.\MessageBreak
          Using fallback driver}%
        \usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@*}}}
       {\blx@error
          {No driver found}
          {I can't find a driver for the entry type
           '\abx@field@entrytype'\MessageBreak
           and there is no fallback driver either}}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\nocite{sigfridsson,ctan,nussbaum}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the bibliography in the MWE: The first two entries are linked to DOI and URL, respectively. The last entry is not linked as it misses both a <code>doi</code> and <code>url</code> field.]

Comment: Highly helpful, thanks! I've created a [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/561883/18258) to this example. Maybe there might be some adjustments required in cases where `biblatex` is used with the `subentry` option.

Comment: This is awesome! Some journals indeed link an entire bibliography entry to a DOI or URL (e.g., _Econometrica_), and this code makes it possible to mimic that style.

Other journals (e.g., the _American Economic Review_) include an icon in front of the entry instead and link this icon to the DOI/URL—probably to avoid long stretches of colored text. I have posted some code in a different thread that does exactly that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/588287/156280.