# Bibtex how to link reference title to the source?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperref, links

I have a bibtex file where every element has a url, e.g:

```
@article{preiner_gaussian-product_2019,
    title = {Gaussian-product subdivision surfaces},
    volume = {38},
    issn = {0730-0301, 1557-7368},
    url = {https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3306346.3323026},
    doi = {10.1145/3306346.3323026},
    language = {en},
    number = {4},
    urldate = {2020-05-22},
    journal = {ACM Transactions on Graphics},
    author = {Preiner, Reinhold and Boubekeur, Tamy and Wimmer, Michael},
    month = jul,
    year = {2019},
    pages = {1--11},
    file = {Full Text:/home/makogan/Zotero/storage/4VCQH8QL/Preiner et al. - 2019 - Gaussian-product subdivision surfaces.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

I am trying to make it so that when I compile the final pdf, the title of the article is linked to the url, e.g:

```
\href{https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3306346.3323026}{Gaussian-product subdivision surfaces}
```

In other words I need to configure the command:

```
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

To guarantee that if available the title in the reference is a clickable link to the original document.

As requested in a comment:
[image]

Comment: Are you using `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

Comment: I am, yes. However it only links the citations to the references, not the references to the source

Comment: Should the the url link show in the ref title? What about showing at the end of the ref entry?

Comment: Can you show a picture example of how you want the reference entry be displayed at the pdf?

Comment: Provided at the bottom of the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are reversing the order of the [\href](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/hyperlinks) inputs. The correct use of `\href` is

```
\href{https://web/address/link}{Text to be displayed}
```

Applying this correction, the output would be

[image]

This is a minimal code of main tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\usepackage{hyperref} % you can add the option [hidelink] if you dont want to show the square box, the links would still be active
\begin{document}
    Check ref.1 \cite{preiner_gaussian-product_2019}.
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

And this is the corrected bib entry configuration in the bib file

```
@article{preiner_gaussian-product_2019,
    title = {\href{https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3306346.3323026}{Gaussian-product subdivision surfaces}},
    volume = {38},
    issn = {0730-0301, 1557-7368},
    url = {https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3306346.3323026},
    doi = {10.1145/3306346.3323026},
    language = {en},
    number = {4},
    urldate = {2020-05-22},
    journal = {ACM Transactions on Graphics},
    author = {Preiner, Reinhold and Boubekeur, Tamy and Wimmer, Michael},
    month = jul,
    year = {2019},
    pages = {1--11},
    file = {Full Text:/home/makogan/Zotero/storage/4VCQH8QL/Preiner et al. - 2019 - Gaussian-product subdivision surfaces.pdf:application/pdf},
}
```

---

Note that this way you did not benefit from the `url` field in your bib entry. If you use another bibliography style (e.g. `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`, the `url` field that you entered will be displayed at the end of the bib entry, like this

[image]

In that case will you still need the ref title be linked to the url by `\href`? Well I guess that's up to you!

Comment: If you further need the entire whole bib entry linking to the url (although it's pretty cumbersome and you may need to switch to `biblatex`), have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464290/91556