# biber, subentry and doi hyperlinks - unwanted spaces inserted before semicolons and periods

Tags: biblatex, biber, doi

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref,style=chem-angew,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{doi}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464215/biblatex-hyperlink-entire-bib-entry-to-doi-url-or-isbn-if-available
\newbibmacro{string+doiurl}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
       {#1}
       {\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
    {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@driver#1{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@#1}
    {\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@#1}}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@bbx@*}
       {\blx@warning{%
          No driver for entry type '#1'.\MessageBreak
          Using fallback driver}%
        \usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@*}}}
       {\blx@error
          {No driver found}
          {I can't find a driver for the entry type
           '\abx@field@entrytype'\MessageBreak
           and there is no fallback driver either}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Salsi2020,
  author       = {Salsi, Federico and Neville, Michael and Drance, Myles and Hagenbach, Adelheid and Chan, Chinglin and Figueroa, Joshua S. and Abram, Ulrich},
  date         = {2020},
  doi          = {10.1039/D0CC03043K},
  journaltitle = {Chem. Commun.},
  volume       = {56},
  pages        = {7009-7012},
}
@article{Claude2020,
  author       = {Claude, Guilhem and Salsi, Federico and Hagenbach, Adelheid and Gembicky, Milan and Neville, Michael and Chan, Chinglin and Figueroa, Joshua S. and Abram, Ulrich},
  date         = {2020},
  doi          = {10.1021/acs.organomet.0c00238},
  journaltitle = {Organometallics},
  volume       = {12},
  pages        = {2287–2294},
}
@article{Figueroa2020,
  author       = {Figueroa, Joshua S. and Abram, Ulrich},
  date         = {2020},
  doi          = {10.1002/zaac.202000147},
  journaltitle = {Z. Anorg. Allg. Chem.},
  pages        = {1--7},
  volume       = {646},
}
@article{Hoffmann1990,
  author       = {Hoffmann, Roald},
  date         = {1991},
  doi          = {10.2307/431761},
  journaltitle = {Interdiscipl. Sci. Rev.},
  pages        = {301--312},
  volume       = {16},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\defbibentryset{set}{Salsi2020,Claude2020,Figueroa2020}

Cite it.\supercite{set} And do it again.\supercite{Hoffmann1990}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

compiles (up-to-date MiKTeX) to give:
[image]

I took the code which adds doi hyperlinks to references from an answer provided by [user moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464290/18258). Unfortunately, I'm not clever enough to figure out what he (or she) did there, but it is working great for me. There is one exception: If there is a set of references within the bibliography, there will somehow be additional spaces before all semicolons and periods, respectively (see ref. 1). This is not the case if a single reference is cited, see ref. 2. Could anybody please assist me in fixing this? The introduced spaces look disappealing and cause line-break trouble in some cases. Those spaces aren't present if the file is compiled with the lines from `\newbibmacro{string+doiurl}[1]{%` to `\makeatother` commented out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is due to a missing `%` in `chem-angew`'s `@article` driver. See https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-chem/pull/19.

Until the pull request above is merged and a new version of `biblatex-chem` with the fix is released you can add the fixed version of the driver to your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newbibmacro{string+doiurl}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
       {#1}
       {\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
    {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@driver#1{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@#1}
    {\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@#1}}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@bbx@*}
       {\blx@warning{%
          No driver for entry type '#1'.\MessageBreak
          Using fallback driver}%
        \usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@*}}}
       {\blx@error
          {No driver found}
          {I can't find a driver for the entry type
           '\abx@field@entrytype'\MessageBreak
           and there is no fallback driver either}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:articletitle}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \newunit
    }
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Salsi2020,
  author       = {Salsi, Federico and Neville, Michael and Drance, Myles and Hagenbach, Adelheid and Chan, Chinglin and Figueroa, Joshua S. and Abram, Ulrich},
  date         = {2020},
  doi          = {10.1039/D0CC03043K},
  journaltitle = {Chem. Commun.},
  volume       = {56},
  pages        = {7009-7012},
}
@article{Claude2020,
  author       = {Claude, Guilhem and Salsi, Federico and Hagenbach, Adelheid and Gembicky, Milan and Neville, Michael and Chan, Chinglin and Figueroa, Joshua S. and Abram, Ulrich},
  date         = {2020},
  doi          = {10.1021/acs.organomet.0c00238},
  journaltitle = {Organometallics},
  volume       = {12},
  pages        = {2287–2294},
}
@article{Figueroa2020,
  author       = {Figueroa, Joshua S. and Abram, Ulrich},
  date         = {2020},
  doi          = {10.1002/zaac.202000147},
  journaltitle = {Z. Anorg. Allg. Chem.},
  pages        = {1--7},
  volume       = {646},
}
@article{Hoffmann1990,
  author       = {Hoffmann, Roald},
  date         = {1991},
  doi          = {10.2307/431761},
  journaltitle = {Interdiscipl. Sci. Rev.},
  pages        = {301--312},
  volume       = {16},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\defbibentryset{set}{Salsi2020,Claude2020,Figueroa2020}

Cite it.\supercite{set} And do it again.\supercite{Hoffmann1990}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography entries without spurious spaces.]