# Changing the style of footfullcite item

Tags: biblatex, citing

Currently `\footfullcite{jdoe2014}` for

```
@inproceedings{jdoe2014,
   author = {John Doe},
   title = {Some paper},
   url = {http://somelink.com/file.pdf},
   year = {2014},
   note = {Rarecon}
}
```

renders into:

> John Doe (2014). "Some paper". In: Rarecon. URL: http://somelink.com/file.pdf

How I can change standard output of this into the

> John Doe (2014). "Some paper". In: Rarecon.

where **"Some paper"** also is PDF link/url to http://somelink.com/file.pdf ?

Comment: What about the bibliography (if you have any)? Do you want the title to link to the paper there as well, or do you prefer to have the link actually displayed with its URL?

Comment: Yes, same for bibliography too.

Comment: Well, OK then this question is just a duplicate of [biblatex: Make title hyperlink to doi url (if available)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23832/35864) or maybe rather [biblatex: make title hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864), don't you think? (I impatiently answered for the case in which one might not want this change to apply to the bibliography.)

Comment: Indeed, sorry, didn't found that one while searching first time.

Comment: You can still use my answer below though, just discard everything in the `\AtBeginBibliography` block.

Answer (score 2):

The following is borrowed from Herbert in [biblatex: Make title hyperlink to doi url (if available)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23832/35864)

We use `doi=false` and `url=false` at load time to suppress DOIs and URLs, but that wont cut it for `@online` entries, so if we want to get rid of the URL there, we also need

```
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{}
```

Then we use Herbert's macro to typeset the title with the link (DOI is preferred to URL)

```
\newbibmacro{string+doiurl}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
          #1%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}
```

The format is applied to the title field

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}
```

To get bibliography back to normal, we then issue

```
\AtBeginBibliography{
  \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
  \settoggle{bbx:url}{true}
  \settoggle{bbx:doi}{true}
  \renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
    \usebibmacro{url}%
    \iffieldundef{urlyear}
      {}
      {\setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{urldate}}}
}
```

To toggle on URLs and DOIs (and revert the old `url` macro) and return to the old title formatting without hyperlinks.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,doi=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{}

\newbibmacro{string+doiurl}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
          #1%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}


\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}

\AtBeginBibliography{
  \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
  \settoggle{bbx:url}{true}
  \settoggle{bbx:doi}{true}
  \renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
    \usebibmacro{url}%
    \iffieldundef{urlyear}
      {}
      {\setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{urldate}}}
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footfullcite{sigfridsson} ipsum\footfullcite{markey} dolor sit\footfullcite{cicero} amet.


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]