# Redirect citation link to DOI instead of citation page

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, doi

In this day and age, if I grab an electronic version of a paper and stumble across a reference, I'd rather be able to access that reference's webpage directly instead of being redirected to the PDF reference page first and then click on the DOI link (if there are any).

So I would like to know how I could make `biblatex`/`hyperref` link to the DOI upon `\cite{}` (if available) instead of disrupting my readers' reading by sending them to another place in the PDF.

Currently, I am using that preamble:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
    bibencoding=utf8,
    backend=biber,
    firstinits=true,
    style=numeric-comp,
    sorting=none,
    natbib=true,
    url=false,
    doi=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=false,
    hidelinks=true,
    unicode
]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
    Blah\cite{foo}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And `bib.bib`:

```
@article{Foo,
    author = {Foo and Bar},
    title = {Foobar},
    journal = {{Foo society}},
    volume = {42},
    number = {42},
    pages = {42},
    year = {2017},
    doi = {10.1021/foo.bar},
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what package and style you use to get your citations and bibliography? Ideally you would show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). A solution will crucially depend on the bibliography package and style you use as well as on other modifications you have made to the style.

Comment: And: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might want to sign up/register to be able to access your question in a few days and comment on it.

Comment: Related, yet no duplicates: [biblatex: Make title hyperlink to doi url (if available)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23832/35864), [biblatex: make title hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864)

Comment: May be, get rid off the first paragraph!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\bibhyperref{#1}}
    {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}
```

Will send you to the DOI if available. If there is no DOI it goes to the bibliography/references at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    firstinits=true,
    style=numeric-comp,
    sorting=none,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}                   
 \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}     

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\bibhyperref{#1}}
    {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```