# How to give hyperlink in bibtex files?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperref

The bib entry is:

```
@article{ball1992, 
title   = "Why does high inflation raise inflation uncertainty?", 
journal = "Journal of Monetary Economics", 
volume  = "29", 
number  = "3", 
pages   = "371-388", 
year    = "1992", 
issn    = "0304-3932",   
doi     = "doi.org/10.1016/0304-3932(92)90032-W", 
url     = "sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439329290032W"‌​, 
author  = "Laurence Ball",
}
```

This is how I currently hard-code the hyperlink to the `title` field:

```
title = {\href{sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439329290032W}{Why 
          does high inflation raise inflation uncertainty?}},
```

I was thinking if there is any easy way to automate this? For example, all the bibtex entries contain url information. Can we use this someway so that we don't have to do it manually?

Comment: Please tell us which document class and which bibliography style you employ. Please also tell us whether you're providing a separate bib field called `doi`.

Comment: Can it be assumed that all bib entries have a field called either `doi` or `url`?

Comment: document class: article and bibliographystyle: chicago   The bib entries have both doi and url.                              @article{BALL1992371,
title = "Why does high inflation raise inflation uncertainty?",
journal = "Journal of Monetary Economics",
volume = "29",
number = "3",
pages = "371 - 388",
year = "1992",
issn = "0304-3932",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3932(92)90032-W",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439329290032W",
author = "Laurence Ball"
}

Comment: You should place the sample bib entry in the body of your posting; that way, it would be much easier to read.

Comment: with biblatex it's easy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available

Comment: @samcarter - The new query is sufficiently different from the earlier ones so as not to make it a pure duplicate. Please provide a new answer, while (naturally) referencing one or two previous postings.

Comment: @Mico I did not say nor vote that this might be a duplicate, just stated that it would be easy if biblatex is used instead.

Comment: So, i have to use biblatex, as @samcarter has suggested....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments