# Cell citation style for biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Using biblatex, is there a way to format the citations and bibliography to match the style for the Cell family of journals?

Search engines reveal .bst files for bibtex, but nothing for biblatex.

Alternately, is there a good reference for how to format a .bbx, assuming no prior experience with biblatex?

Comment: For the alternative version of the question, [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/105447) is a good starting point.

Comment: If you plan to submit to the journal, you should take into account that even if they accept LaTeX submissions they probably will not be able to handle `biblatex`: [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). If you have to use Cell style and there already is a predefined `.bst` file that ticks all the boxes (does not need to be changed to comply with Cell guidelines at all) you don't have to use `biblatex`, you can go on using the `.bst` file (if you don't need any of `biblatex`'s advanced features that is).

Comment: @moewe - The advanced feature I want to preserve is changing the titles to hyperlink to the doi. This is for review -- I'll worry about submission later. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Cell [instruction for authors](http://www.cell.com/cell/authors) only give examples for articles, books, and chapters/proceedings, modifying the standard style is not all that daunting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Some general changes
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
    \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{inproceedings}{%
        \printtext{\bibstring{in}\addspace}%
    }{}%
}

% Changes for Book
\csletcs{abx@macro@publisher+location+date@orig}{abx@macro@publisher+location+date}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date@orig}}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1\printunit{\addspace}}

% Changes for inproceedings
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1\addcomma}
\xpatchbibmacro{byeditor+others}{%
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
    \clearname{editor}%
}{%
    \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
    \clearname{editor}
    \addcomma\addspace
    \bibstring{editor}
    \setunit{\addspace}%
}{}{}

% Changes in Article
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{SL00,
  author = {Sondheimer, N and Lindquist, S},
  year = {2000},
  title = {Rnq1: an epigenetic modifier of protein function in yeast.},
  journaltitle = {Mol. Cell},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {163--172}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{King03,
  author = {King, S M},
  editor = {M Schliwa},
  title = {Dynein motors: Structure, mechanochemistry and regulation},
  booktitle = {Molecular Motors},
  publisher = {Wiley-VCH Verlag GmbH},
  pages = {45--78},
  address = {Weinheim, Germany},
  year = {2003}
}
@BOOK{CJZ97,
  author = {Cowan, W M and Jessell, T M and Zipursky, S L},
  title = {Molecular and Cellular Approaches to Neural Development},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  address = {New York},
  year = {1997}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

See examples at \url{http://www.cell.com/cell/authors}

\noindent Cowan, W.M., Jessell, T.M., and Zipursky, S.L. (1997). Molecular and Cellular Approaches to Neural Development (New York: Oxford University Press).

\noindent King, S.M. (2003). Dynein motors: Structure, mechanochemistry and regulation. In Molecular Motors, M. Schliwa, ed. (Weinheim, Germany: Wiley-VCH Verlag GmbH), pp. 45--78.

\noindent Sondheimer, N., and Lindquist, S. (2000). Rnq1: an epigenetic modifier of protein function in yeast. Mol. Cell \textit{5}, 163--172.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```