# Bibtex hyperlinks to title entries in bibliography when urls is available

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, doi, hyperlink

I would like to do something like that in the someone's previous post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available). But it doesn't work with my thesis. I have almost all of the bibliography entries with 'note' which include url to specific website. Most of the time there is doi webpage. I want to achieve hyperlink to all urls which will shows as clickable title in bibliography. So let's suppose I have this two entries (one with doi, one with some http/https links):

```
@article{heo,
    author = {He, Q.F. and Ding, Z.Y. and Ye, Y.F. and al., et},
    journal = {JOM},
    volume = {7},
    number = {69},
    language = {English},
    pages = {2092--2098},
    title = {Design of High-Entropy Alloy: A Perspective from Nonideal Mixing},
    year = {2017},
    doi = {10.1007/s11837-017-2452-1},
    note = {doi: \url{https://doi.org/10.1007/s11837-017-2452-1}},
}
@article{calphad,
author = {Wróbel, M. and Burbelko, A.},
year = {2014},
pages = {79--84},
title = {Metoda CALPHAD – nowoczesna technika pozyskiwania danych termodynamicznych},
volume = {14},
journal = {Archives of Foundry Engineering},
note = {Dostęp na 02.04.2020: \url{http://www.afe.polsl.pl/index.php/pl/4073/metoda-calphad-nowoczesna-technika-pozyskiwania-danych-termodynamicznych.pdf}},
}
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Are you using bibtex or biblatex?  Which bibliography style?

Comment: I compiled my biblio as `bibtex sample.aux` in command line tool so I believe it is bibtex. I use `plunsrt` style

Comment: The example that you have been looking at is for `biblatex`, which is has greater flexibility than `bibtex`.  The `plunsrt.bst` style does not support the `url = {..},` field, although some other `.bst` styles for `bibtex` do.  One approach would be to edit the `plunsrt.bst` file, but this would be a project.  Another might be to adopt `biblatex`.  Perhaps others on this forum can offer a more precise idea.

Comment: Dear @John, thank you for your answer. I'm not the specialist of tex but I'm sure that 'url' works pretty well in my case. Also `\href` in title section works, but I have to change every single entry by my own... which is annoying. So maybe I have biblatex (I don't know, I just use what starts work when I put it in my code). I suppose bibtex because like I already say - I use `bibtex sample.aux` command.

Comment: For clarification, some `.bst` styles allow you to include a field `url = { ...},` which is processed by bibtex.  The `\url{..}` macro in the `note = { ...},` field is actually processed by latex, not bibtex.  When bibtex sets the title as a hyperlinked field, it's normally because is it looking at the `url = {..},` field. What you mention about putting `\href` in the `title={..}` field is a workaround, but as you mention not automatic.

Comment: Do you use the `plunsrt` bib style because your document is in Polish? (`plunsrt` is basically a version of the `unsrt` that's been adapted to using Polish rather than English particles for "and", "and others", etc.)  If so, maybe you should modify your question to ask how the newer `unsrtnat` bib style might be modified to feature Polish rather than English particles. (The `unsrtnat` bib style knows about fields such as `url` and `doi`, whereas `unsrt` and `plunsrt` do not.)

Comment: I agree with Mico's idea -- it would be much easier to change the particles.