# Reference section links formatting

Tags: biblatex

I'm a total beginner to LaTeX trying to write my thesis using it.
Currently for bibliographical citations I'm using `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex}`. `style=ieee` ensures that the citations appear inline as `[3]`, `[4]`, etc and in the order I introduce them (and Reference section is reordered accordingly). I don't want that to change!

Now, here's what my references section looks like

[image]

whereas, I want to

1. get rid of the `[Online] Available:` and the URL;
2. instead, hyperlink the title to the URL

Kinda like this:

[image]

except that I'd like to keep the IEEE style for the rest of the reference if possible. How can I do that?

Comment: Please add a minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB) of your current setup.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh My thesis project can be found on Overleaf at http://overleaf.com/read/jwthpgnjwtbg. Sorry I'm not really experienced enough to know exactly which parts are feeding into bibliography and which aren't (except what I said in the OP)

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864 (which was inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23832/35864), that appears to be a pretty good duplicate for this question. If you can't get the answer to work, we'll need to see a real MWE (in the style of the MWE in that answer) to see what is going on.

Comment: More help on MWEs can be found in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864. For bibliography-related questions in `biblatex` it is usually enough to throw together a small document loading `biblatex` with your options and a few example `.bib` entries.

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to get https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864 to work for you?

Comment: @moewe not really, I didn't really feel like I understood the reply there. But I have a working solution which is just to replace the title with a hyperlink. Of course I have to (1) find the hyperlink myself, (2) fill it in manually like this. But since (1) probably can't be solved by LaTeX, and (2) isn't that much worse than just putting it in the .bib separately, we're probably good?

Comment: Hrmm, if I take the accepted answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864 and just change `\usepackage[doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}` and change it to `\usepackage[style=ieee, doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}` for IEEE style I get something with linked titles that looks like it would be what you are looking for. If you have specific questions about the code I suggest you edit your question, if not I'd say it's a duplicate.