# How to get linkable titles in all entries in which a url is provided?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, urls

I want the titles of every entry in my bibliography to have links to their respective urls if and only if some url is provided, while keeping urls out of sight. I have found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available) and [this other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn) similar questions, on whose answers I have based my approach. Unfortunately, I can't get the desired result. See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newbibmacro{string+doi}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{url}{#1}{\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/}
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}
@incollection{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}
@phdthesis{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Delta},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

As you can see in the schreenshot below, the problem is that the entry types other than `@book` `@article` do not get linkeable titles despite a url being provided. How can I get the desired effect bot only for the `@book` and `@article` classes but for `@incollection`, `@phdthesis` and `@inbook` classes too?

[image]

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `title` formats are (see [`biblatex.def`, ll. 579-585 in v3.18](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/868b79fecb7998742eae53d2f81bb637453ceaf7/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L579-L585))

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{#1}
```

In order to replicate them with linking you want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newbibmacro{string+doi}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{url}{#1}{\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/}
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}
@incollection{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}
@phdthesis{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Delta},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: All titles in pink to show linking.]

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1}}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}%
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}
```

(or
`\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection,thesis, inbook]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}`)

and changing the before the last reference to

```
@thesis{D04,
        author = {Duthor, D.},
        type   = {phdthesis},
        year = {2004},
        title = {Delta},
        url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},          
    }
```

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex}    
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newbibmacro{string+doi}[1]{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{#1}{\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1}}} % added
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}% added
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}% added
    
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @article{A01,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
        url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/}
    }
    @book{B02,
        author = {Buthor, B.},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Bravo},
        url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},
    }
    @incollection{C03,
        author = {Cuthor, C.},
        year = {2003},
        title = {Charlie},
        booktitle     = "Fiber Optic Test and Measurement",
        url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},
    }
    @thesis{D04,
        author = {Duthor, D.},
        type   = {phdthesis},
        year = {2004},
        title = {Delta},
        url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},  
    }

    @inbook{E05,
        author        = "H. E. Rose",
        title         = "A Course in Number Theory",
        publisher     = "Oxford Univ. Press",
        address       = "New York, NY",
        year          = "1988",
        url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},
        chapter       = "3"
    }
    
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

The last reference taken from `biblatex-examples.bib`