# How to hyper link paper name, vol, issue, year in biblatex as shown in image below?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, href

```
@article{PhysRevLett.13.138,
   title = {Evidence for the $2\ensuremath{\pi}$ Decay of the $K_{2}^{0}$ Meson},
   author = {Christenson, J. H. and Cronin, J. W. and Fitch, V. L. and Turlay, R.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
    volume = {13},
    issue = {4},
     pages = {138--140},
     numpages = {0},
     year = {1964},
     month = {Jul},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
   doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.13.138},
   url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.13.138}
   }
```

I am using bibtex for the references. I want to hyperlink the journal part as shown in the figure. Can anyone suggest how to do this?
[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864 answers the question asked in the title, but not the one asked in the question body. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27752/35864 discusses the question asked in the body.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2777/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314390/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/676072/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464215/35864

Comment: I have edited the question according to the body. Is there a solution to the above code to produce the result as shown in the image.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27752/35864 link not help?

Comment: Do I need to add that long code? It seems to very complicated. Also I am using \bibliographystyle{unsrt} package in the main tex file. And \bibliography{ref.bib} is imported. I have many citations..So simply citations are copied in .bib format from the journal link and made a .bib file as given in the question

Comment: If you're using `\bibliographystyle`, you're not using `biblatex` as the tag suggested. The linked answers will also not work for you, because they are based on `biblatex`. I'll retag your question to make sure you get hints that actually work for your setup.